# Size rule not working in logrotate

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logrotate

I created a log-rotate option for our docker logs and it is working fine. Here is the configuration file

```
*root@aerogear:/var/lib/docker/containers/b8da13f8dc6cb642959103c23db2a02ef2c7291ae5f94625a92ac9329db1647e# cat /etc/logrotate.d/docker-container
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {
  rotate 7
  hourly
  compress
  size=100M
  missingok
  delaycompress
  copytruncate
}*
```

It seems that hourly logrotate is working fine. But because of some error, this log file was increased up to 18G, because the `size=100M` rule didn't work in that case. Do you know any specific reason for that?

Answer (score 6):

- There shouldn't be an equal sign after `size`.
- If you want to rotate both hourly **and** when the file grows bigger than `100M`, then you should use `maxsize` instead of `size`.

So you should try `maxsize 100M` instead of `size=100M`.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by Ronan, `size` and `hourly` are "contradictory". One or the other may be used, but it is likely that one has priority, so you need to use `maxsize` instead.

Next:

> Normally,  logrotate  is  run  as a daily cron job.  It will not modify a log more than once in one day unless the criterion for that log is based on the log's size and logrotate is being run more than once each  day,  or  unless the `-f` or `--force` option is used.
>
> *(from logrotate manual page)*

On a standard Ubuntu installation, `logrotate` runs once per day. If you look at the cron installation, you will see `logrotate` under the `cron.daily` directory:

```
prompt$ ls -l /var/cron.daily
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  372 May  6  2015 logrotate
...
```

And there is nothing under `cron.hourly`:

```
prompt$ ls -l /var/cron.hourly
(nothing)
```

This shows that an `hourly` setup for `logrotate` is not going to be responding any more than a `daily` setup on a default setup. Of course, you can change that and get `logrotate` to run once an hour or even once a minute (in this last case, you need a crontab for `root`). But by default a `maxsize` with an `hourly` or `daily` setup is not useful since the file will be rotated each time anyway, whatever the size.

Also there has been versions of `logrotate` where the `maxsize` parameter did not work. This should not be an issue in the newer versions.

And as Ronan mentioned, no `=` sign between the option and value.

Comment: Why will the hourly setup for logrotate not respond any more than a daily setup? What if we move the logrotate script to /cron.hourly ?

Comment: @Ryanw Yes. I mentioned you could move the script to run hourly or even once a minute. To get a minute run, you need to move the script somewhere else (may `/root`) and use the root `crontab` for that purpose, but if you have many logs that is likely going to be way too much--a huge I/O hog.

Comment: Do you know why the max size will not work with an hourly setup?

Comment: @Ryanw I made an update to my answer. I think it will be easier to understand. If you use `hourly` and run logrotate every hour, then the files will be rotate every hour, whatever the size. So having that parameter won't help (it's just noise).